# I m trying to check weather the selected fields have exist or not but its not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

bellow my code is perfectly fine and working but I want to check if connec.reader.HasRows then redirect the user to page.aspx else pop up a message with "you have not registered". Please can anyone help me why is this not working. Help is appreciated.

This Code is from my Manager Class.

```
public static void Insert(string _username, string _password)
        {


            Connection connec = new Connection();
            connec.SqlQuery("select * from manager where UserName='@username' AND Password='@password'");
            connec.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", _username);
            connec.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", _password);
            connec.QueryReader();
    }
```

The code bellow is from page.aspx page to act upon the method.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ManagerClass connec = new ManagerClass();

                ManagerClass.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);

        }
```

Comment: change `"select * from manager where UserName='@username' AND Password='@password'`" to `"select * from manager where UserName=@username AND Password=@password"`.

Comment: but how do I add the condition to check if the manager put the username and password correct then redirect to this page.aspx page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the code structure which you need to correct. Instead of `void Insert` method you should have method `bool IsValidUser` as following. Also this method need not be static method. It should be instance method.

```
public bool IsValidUser(string _username, string _password)
{
    Connection connec = new Connection();
    connec.SqlQuery("select COUNT(*) from manager where UserName=@username AND Password=@password");
    connec.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", _username);
    connec.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", _password);

    int userCount = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    con.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    return userCount != 0;
}
```

Now in your page you call this method and check the value returned by the method. If it's false then show message else redirect user to the page.aspx.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManagerClass managerObj = new ManagerClass();

    if(managerObj.IsValidUser(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text))
    {
         Response.Redirect("page.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
         //Show message "you have not registered";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (TextBox1.Text != string.Empty && TextBox2.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        Connection connec = new Connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM manager WHERE userName=@userName and password=@password", connec);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            // do something here. (ex: get logs/date/session datas)
        }
        else
        {
            // you have not registered! (Show your warning message here)
            Response.Redirect("register.aspx"); //(or use your popup here)
        }
        con.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        Response.Redirect("page.aspx");
    }

    else
    {
        // _userName and _password cannot be null! (your message here)
    }
```